# How to setup HornetQ Demo

Tags: hornetq

I'm trying to recreate the HornetQ examples with my own test projects.  However I'm having class loader issues.  Obviously I'm missing some dependencies that are not specified in the docs.

The docs had me add

- `hornetq-core-client.jar`
- `netty.jar`
- `hornetq-jms-client.jar`
- `jboss-jms-api.jar`

I'm getting this error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:
   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory 
[Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory]
```

Where can I find this class (and any others that might be needed)?

Comment: Can you tell me which HQ version you are using and where in the documentation that you found this JAR list? Was this taken from `examples/jms/applet/applet.html`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently hit the same issue.  Recreating the topic example, i had to add the following:

jnp-client.jar
hornetq-commons.jar

Both should be in the hornetq lib

Answer (score 1):

For what is worth, starting with **HornetQ 2.3** everything has been Mavenized. So if you ever have trouble figuring out a dependency list for a HornetQ example, just change into the example's folder and ask Maven:

```
cd hornetq/examples/jms/topic
mvn dependency:list
```